# How to make sliding content from home layout to default layout

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-10.x

I'm using Typo3 10 and bootstrap_package,

I want to learn how to get benefit from this fluid code for sliding content from home page to the subpages.
Frontpage has a selected backend layout (Special_start)
Subpages has selected backend layout (Default)..

```
    <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.dynamicContent" data="{pageUid: '{data.uid}', colPos: '3', slide: '{theme.pagelayout.{pagelayout}.colPos.3.slide}'}" />
```

Is there a simple solution with fluid to make the content in colpos 3 sliding in all subpages?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this (only bootstrap package):

https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/wiki/Allow-content-slide-configuration-for-all-layouts-and-colPos

https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/commit/159dda4dc614d0468559615c51b6a457e22006f3

> It is now possible to make content columns slide without touching the
> templates. The typoscript lib for content selection now accepts a
> slide parameter, that can be used to define the data collection
> behaviour.
>
> Allowed Values:
>
> ```
> -1 = back up to the siteroot
> 0 = default, no slide
> 1 = only the current level
> 2 = up from one level back
> ```
>
> TypoScript Constants Example:
>
> ```
> page.theme.pagelayout.<pagelayout>.colPos.<colPos>.slide = -1
> page.theme.pagelayout.pagets__default.colPos.9.slide = -1
> ```
>
> Fluid Example:
>
> ```
> <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.dynamicContent" data="{colPos: '9', slide: '-1'}" />
> ```

If you want to slide colPos 3 of the default template (bootstrap package) try:

```
page.theme.pagelayout.default.colPos.3.slide = -1
```

Answer (score 1):

For understanding the sliding mechanism you may need to know about the original configuration in the first TYPO3 versions:

You had prebuild a backend-layout which differs 4 columns and which content could be assigned to special areas of the final frontend layout.
each content (`tt_content`record) was assigned to one of these columns. the column is one field in the `tt_content`record: 0 = main, 1 = left, 2 = right, 3 = border.
Meanwhile the columns are easily expandable and the basic layout consists of only one column.
Nevertheless you can use more column in your page rendering (FLUID). Especially if you use sliding content.

In the origin the rendering was done in typoscript and each column got a simple part of typoscript to compute the html from the records. (`styles.content.get`  with derivates about column number and slide mechanism).
In TYPO3 bootstrap you still use it as the VH `<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.dynamicContent" ...` just specifies some parameters what records should be rendered to HTML to insert in the frontend rendering (FLUID).

from the typoscript of `ext:bootstrap_package`:

```
#  EXAMPLE
#  ---------------
#  <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.dynamicContent" data="{
#      pageUid: '{data.uid}',
#      colPos: '0',
#      slide: '0',
#      wrap: '<div class=\"hero\">|</div>',
#      elementWrap: '<div class=\"element\">|</div>'
#  }" />
```

Your BE layout does not need to match exactly (column wise) what you want to render in the frontend. Especially sliding columns don't need to be editable in pages beyond the main/ start page.

Comment: Thank you but when i put this                         
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.dynamicContent" data="{pageUid: '{data.uid}', colPos: '3'}" />

in the subpage layout "Default" i don't get anything in frontend, so what i'm missing here ?

Comment: I added the example call with all parameters in my answer. you need to provide the `uid` from your root page, or the `slide` parameter to access data from another page than the current.